# Implementing asinfotrack\yii2-wiki Module not found

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm implementing this package following the instructions found [here](https://github.com/asinfotrack/yii2-wiki).

In my config, as instructed, I have

```
'wiki'=>[
            'class'=>'asinfotrack\yii2\wiki\Module',
            'processContentCallback'=>function($content) {
            //example if you want to use markdown in your wiki
            return Parsedown::instance()->parse($content);
            }
        ]
```

I am getting an error on wiki/content/view?id=index: Class 'app\modules\wiki\Module' not found - what have I missed?

[image]

Comment: Can you show the complete error message? And where exactly you have put the above mentioned code in the config file.

Comment: @gojiraki in the config file, it's under modules:
    'modules' => [
        'gii' => [
            'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
            'allowedIPs' => ['*'] // adjust this to your needs
        ],
        'wiki'=>[
            'class'=>'asinfotrack\yii2\wiki\Module',
            'processContentCallback'=>function($content) {
            //example if you want to use markdown in your wiki
            return Parsedown::instance()->parse($content);

Comment: @gojiraki further error details 1. in /home/security/yii-application/vendor/asinfotrack/yii2-wiki/models/Wiki.php. 

            'content' => Yii::t('app', 'Content'),
        ];
    }
 
    /**
     * --inheritdoc
     */
    public static function find()
    {
        $queryClass = Module::getInstance()->queryClass;
        return new $queryClass(get_called_class());
    }
 
    public function getIsOrphan()
    {
        return !static::find()->withLinkToArticle($this->id)->exists();
    }
 
    public function getContentProcessed()

Comment: Please share the full screenshot of the error

Comment: @Abhishekkandari added

Comment: Are you getting error on index page also. As in the answer provided below it seems to be wrong namespace error.

Comment: @gojiraki yes, I followed the advice which resolved the error. I think this package is incomplete and very buggy though as there are more errors now! Any suggestions on a wiki for yii2?

Comment: Please share more screenshot of the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is [wrong](https://github.com/asinfotrack/yii2-wiki/blob/3dfc280fa8060bcad6588a5af05b1fe2a0a310a2/models/Wiki.php#L5) class namespace used in the package by the developer i.e `app\modules\wiki\Module` instead of  `asinfotrack\yii2\wiki\Module`
to fix this issue without changing the code in the vendor you can set the classmap on top of the project config file( *common.php* or *main.php* ) like this

```
Yii::$classMap['app\modules\wiki\Module'] = VENDOR_PATH.'/toasinfotrack/yii2-wiki/Module.php';
```

More details about classmapping in Yii2 can be found [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-autoloading#class-map)

Comment: Thanks - that worked. The package unfortunately doesn't though...